# django serializers tries to reference variable before assigning inside try-except block

Tags: django

This is my view for getting 3 objects and returning to template using ajax

```
def getText(request):
    l=request.POST.get('lid','')
    n=request.POST.get('cid','')
    o=request.POST.get('pid','')
    # print(l)
    try:
        lb=books.objects.get(id=l)
        con=contacts.objects.get(id=n)
        mo=movies.objects.get(id=o)
    except books.DoesNotExist:
        lb=None
    except contacts.DoesNotExist:
        con=None
    except movies.DoesNotExist:
        mo=None
    serialized_obj = serializers.serialize('json', [ lb,con,mo ])
    return HttpResponse(serialized_obj,content_type='application/json')
```

I am getting the following error **UnboundLocalError: local variable 'mo' referenced before assignment**

Comment: Because one of lb or con was not found, so it never gets to the line where mo is defined. You should have separate try/except statements for each query.

Comment: you need to assign default parameter before try bock for `mo`  variable.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yh.No error now. Thanks. Tried to do all the three queries in a single try. Guess that's not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an exception is raised in a `try` block, the first matching handler (`except` block) is executed, **then the execution jumps to the first statement after the whole `try/except`** (nb: assuming there's a matching handler of course). So in your case:

```
try:
    lb=books.objects.get(id=l)
    con=contacts.objects.get(id=n)
    mo=movies.objects.get(id=o)
except books.DoesNotExist:
    lb=None
except contacts.DoesNotExist:
    con=None
except movies.DoesNotExist:
    mo=None 

serialized_obj = serializers.serialize('json', [ lb,con,mo ])
```

if the first statement in the try block raises a `Book.DoesNotExist`, the execution flow jumps to the first `except` clause (which sets `lb` to `None`, __then it jumps to the `serialized_obj = serializers.serialize('json', [ lb,con,mo ])` statement. At this point, neither `con` nor `mo` have been deined, hence you error.

There are two possible solutions here: the first is to use one `try/except` per statement, ie:

```
try:
    lb=books.objects.get(id=l)
except books.DoesNotExist:
    lb=None
try:
    con=contacts.objects.get(id=n)
except contacts.DoesNotExist:
    con=None
try:
    mo=movies.objects.get(id=o)
except movies.DoesNotExist:
    mo=None
```

which is a good practice (it's very explicit, each try block has the minimal possible code in it etc) but a bit on the verbose side. In your case, the other (simpler) solution is to first define all three names as `None` then proceed with the try/except, with an empty `except` clause, ie:

```
lb=None
con=None
mo=None 

try:
    lb=books.objects.get(id=l)
    con=contacts.objects.get(id=n)
    mo=movies.objects.get(id=o)
except (books.DoesNotExist, contacts.DoesNotExist, movies.DoesNotExist):
    pass
```

Comment: Perfect.your second solution is exactly what i was hoping to do. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are not having contacts with id=n.
So the exception is getting thrown

`except contacts.DoesNotExist:
        con=None`

and con gets assigned None

Thus `mo=movies.objects.get(id=o)` is not executed.

`serialized_obj = serializers.serialize('json', [ lb,con,mo ])` gets executed next and Thus mo referenced before assignment

Answer (score 0):

In this code if books or contacts doesn't exists then it goes to the corresponding exception and sets it as `None` but `mo` remains undefined.